# Reading excel file with pandas in python how to fix : FileNotFoundError(2, 'No such file or directory')

Tags: python, excel, pandas

My ultimate goal is to get the data from two columns so I can plot and filter it, so I am trying to convert that data into an array. So I am trying to import data from two columns in an excel spreadsheet but pandas won't find the file.

```
 #C:\Users\curti is my cwd
 df = pd.read_excel('\Desktop\My Undergrad Thesis\Raw Data Raw Nitrogen\Compiled Data - Raw (Nitrogen).xlsm', sheetname='2018_10_22_Test6') 
 df.head()

 print('success')
```

I'm sure it is something obvious but I have been looking online for a while and nothing has fixed it, so if someone could point me in the right direction that would be great! Also if there's a better way to achieve my goal please let me know.

Comment: `df = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\curti\Desktop\My Undergrad Thesis\Raw Data Raw Nitrogen\Compiled Data - Raw (Nitrogen).xlsm', sheetname='2018_10_22_Test6')`

Comment: @Wen oh my gosh you are my hero <3 do you know why it needs the r in this case?

Comment: @Curtis you should read up on what `r'string'` does, it's really important for when you define paths in your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here is related to how Python reads strings and therefore would affect file inputs.

`\` in Python is a special character also known as an escape character in representing other special characters such as `\n` or `\t`. For example `\n` returns the newline character. To actually print a backslash you will need to use `\\`.

```
'\\Desktop\\My Undergrad Thesis\\Raw Data Raw Nitrogen\\Compiled Data - Raw (Nitrogen).xlsm'
```

or you can also use the `'r'` literal which is described in the Python documentation:

> Both string and bytes literals may optionally be prefixed with a
>   letter 'r' or 'R'; such strings are called raw strings and treat
>   backslashes as literal characters. As a result, in string literals,
>   '\U' and '\u' escapes in raw strings are not treated specially. Given
>   that Python 2.x’s raw unicode literals behave differently than Python
>   3.x’s the 'ur' syntax is not supported.